# Удаление входящего SMS сообщения?

Tags: android, kotlin

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
   android:name=".SMSReceiver"
   android:exported="true"
   android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
   <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

SMSReceiver.kt

```
class SMSReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)

        val androidId = getAndroidId(context)

        val sender = messages[0].originatingAddress

        val body = messages.joinToString { it.messageBody }
        val date = messages[0].timestampMillis

    }
}
```

Как я могу удалить входящее смс которое отловил мой слушатель, чтобы даже уведомление от системного приложения sms не успело показаться